# Split a ZFS clone?

Tags: zfs

Is it possible to split a zfs clone to allow the original snapshot to be destroyed?

```
# zfs create zpool1/test1
# zfs snapshot zpool1/test1@snap1
# zfs clone zpool1/test1@snap1 zpool1/test1clone
# zfs destroy zpool1/test1@snap1
cannot destroy 'zpool1/test1@snap1': snapshot has dependent clones
use '-R' to destroy the following datasets:
zpool1/test1clone
#
```

At this point, it would like to 'actualize' the zpool1/test1clone file system, essentially as if I had performed a `zfs send zpool1/test1@snap1 | zfs receive zpool1/test1clone`.

Answer (score 7):

You would need to promote the ZFS clone to a filesystem in order to be able to destroy the original snapshot/filesystem.

`zfs promote zpool1/test1clone`

Please see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gcvfl/index.html

```
zfs promote filesystem
     Promotes a clone file system to no longer  be  dependent
     on its "origin" snapshot. This makes it possible to des-
     troy the file system that the clone  was  created  from.
     The   clone   parent-child  dependency  relationship  is
     reversed, so that the "origin"  file  system  becomes  a
     clone of the specified file system.
```

Comment: promote doesn't really do what I want, as all it seems to do really seems to do is move the snapshot from the original file system onto the cloned filesystem, and then setups a dependency the other way around, meaning the original filesystem now has a dependency. I want to remove any dependencies between the file systems

Comment: Rename the promoted filesystem.

Comment: Matthew is right. `zfs list -t all -o name,origin,clones -r zpool1` shows the clone hierarchy.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want there to be any ties between the child and parent filesystems, you will have to do a zfs send/receive.